# How to create datepicker for android using react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

React native has DatePickerIOS, but it works only on ios.
How to create the same functionality on android?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: Try using  https://github.com/pandiaraj44/react-native-datepicker-dialog for easy implementation of date-picker for both android and ios.

Comment: https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

Answer (score 3):

I know thats and old question but I will leave that answer here anyway.

React native now supports a [datepicker for Android as well](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid.html#content).

Answer (score 1):

follow below link instruction for android datepicker:-

http://react-components.com/component/react-native-date

and for date replace the handleClick function with

```
handleClick: function () {
 NativeModules.DateAndroid.showDatepicker(function() {}, function(year, month, day) {
    alert(year + ":" + month+ ":" + day);
  });
},
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

DatePickerAndroid is still not available in the current version of React Native (0.14.2).

You can use [this module](https://github.com/nucleartux/react-native-date) implemented by a third party. It's not the official one but it's a good temporary solution until React Native implements the proper one.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe have other solutions without editing react-native files?

Comment: Whats the problem using this module? I use it for my App, it has Date and Time Picker which works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

> react native datePicker component for both Android and IOS, useing DatePikcerAndroid, TimePickerAndroid and DatePickerIOS

Answer (score 0):

React Native now supports an Android Date Picker, but it's still a completely separated component that works in a different way. There are several modules making it easier to implement it simultaneously for both platforms. For instance my own module https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker but there are tons of others out there.